# PHP generated output on the same html page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, output

I have got a WordPress site running and I want to offer a calorie calculator.

The html part is ready and the php script does what it should, BUT I want the php to create a output on the same html site under the input forms.

A other site solved that great:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dsem8vj23qmqodr/Ask%20Stack.jpg?dl=0

I don't want to show my php file here, because of the calculation algorithm.

Someone told me it is possible WITHOUT sql to handle that problem. As I get that right it is about giving the inputvalues back to the html and create a outputfield... But unfortunately the guy is not contactable atm.

If you need the code, I will post it, but I think it is possible to help without.

Some more Infos:

- php and html are two files
- I want to put 8 values out, in a table like on the picture.
- (if I have to) I have no clue how to contact the sql server via wordpress.

Comment: Hello @Joeykenoy - It would really help others help you if you posted some of the code that you've tried and what results you got. Hide anything that is sensitive. From the sounds of it, the calculation you reference has nothing to do with the core problem. Cheers.

Comment: KJH is absolutely right you should abstract your code. It would be even enough if you abstract your algorithm to `$a + $b = $output` but we have to see how it all plays together. How you fetch, calculate and deploy the data. Regards

Comment: Thx for your answers. Code in a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you don't need sql for that, providing you have all the required calorie data hardcoded in your PHP script.

What you need to do is send a form, and if there was a $_POST data you just display the result produced by your script, below the form.

More neat solution would be to collect the form data with JS and make an AJAX call to your PHP calculation script, then display the result below the form with JS.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thx for your answer, but I dont get it together with my code.
I added some more informations.

Answer (score 0):

Thx for your answer, but I don't get it together with my code. I am a rookie. -.-

This are the values I get from the html forms:

```
$kfa = $_POST['kfa'];
$groesse = $_POST['groesse'];
$gewicht = $_POST['gewicht'];
$beruf = $_POST['beruf'];
$ziel = $_POST['ziel'];
$ewb = $_POST['ewbedarf'];
```

(body fat percentage, height, weight, job, goal and protein need)

The php script calculates on that base the output values:

```
$wochenverbrauch
$tagesverbrauch
$freizeitumsatz
$arbeitsumsatz
$protein
$kohlenhydrate
$fette
```

(calories needed: week, day, in free time, at work and protein, carbs and fat intake)

The first values (user input in the forms) should be "active" in the form after the calculation AND the table of the second values should be displayed under the forms.

Here is the html file, hope it says more than my text (I cut out a lot of input values for here): 
[https://pastebin.com/J7imKpqz][1]

I tried to paste it here, after half an hour I gave up. I don't know why the editor says there is code not proper formatted.